# EmberJS - Printing model properties when multiple models on a route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I currently have two models being loaded from the same route using the following code:

```
    model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      sginp: this.get('store').query('sginp', params),
      weekdayplan: this.get('store').query('weekdayplan', params),
        });
  },

  setupController(controller, models) {
    controller.set('sginp', models.sginp);
    controller.set('weekdayplan', models.weekdayplan);

  }
```

Both of the models load correctly in Ember Data.

I would like to be able to display the values of different model properties in different parts of my page.

As per a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409782/emberjs-how-to-print-values-from-model-outside-of-each-type-functions) I have been doing this with {{model.firstObject.property}} when I have had one single model and it works fine.

I assumed I would be able to do something like:

```
{{model.sginp.name}} {{model.weekdayplan.day}}
{{models.sginp.name}} {{models.weekdayplan.day}}
```

But these (and a number of permutations) do not display anything when used and no errors are generated in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1., don't forget to call `this._super(controller, models);` on the first line of `setupController(controller, models)`

2., in your template use some of these `{{model.sginp.firstObject.name}} {{sginp.firstObject.name}} {{model.weekdayplan.firstObject.day}} {{weekdayplan.firstObject.day}}`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. {{modelname.firstObject.property}} was the ticket. If I may ask, what does  this._super(controller, model)' do? When I add it to my setupController it actually kills my ability to render the page on this route. I've added it above my first controller.set line ---- nevermind, I am a bufoon and had a syntax error. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: It sets the model property upon the controller as follows:
    `/** 
    @method setupController
    @param {Controller} controller instance
    @param {Object} model
    @since 1.0.0
    @public
  */
  setupController(controller, context, transition) {
    if (controller && (context !== undefined)) {
      set(controller, 'model', context);
    }
  },`
[source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/ca82befb9c41bc92fef8b5865bb16ae7c32f25e0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1746)